# update openshift git repository after changes are made by client

Tags: php, git, openshift, git-pull

I have a php app on openshift with mysql and manage it through git. I can easily add photos to my local clone and push it up to git and it works fine. But when a client uploads a photo through my site, to the openshift server, that uploaded photo (via php $_FILE) doesn't get pushed into the git repo and when I pull git repo to my local machine I can't find that uploaded photo. Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that those photo's are being stored in your `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` which by default isn't tracked in your git repo. I would suggest setting up a rsync cron job that will sync any new files from your `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` to your local machine.

Something like:
`rsync -raz --progress /var/www openshift_ssh_information:~/app-root/data/`

Comment: those photos are inside the git repository, not the $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR

Comment: This is sloppy but you could use the cron cart to execute git commands every so often. But I would suggest editing your app to store images in the `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` as its persistent storage on your gear and then use rsync to copy the data.